# How can I prevent popup from getting closed by the escape key in IntelliJ IDEA/PhpStorm/Pycharm/Rubymine?

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm, rubymine, ideavim

-- UPDATE --

the new version of ideaVim plugin fixed this issue already.

I'm using PhpStorm under ubuntu with ideaVim plugin.

One thing annoying me is when I edit in the popup windows such as show diff editor I need to press <kbd>Escape</kbd> to switch to Vim normal mode, but the popup window still gets closed.

I can't find any settings to change or disable <kbd>Escape</kbd> key mapping in PhpStorm for closing the popups.

Comment: See https://github.com/JetBrains/ideavim#escape, http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/VIM-193, http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/VIM-424.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the new version of ideaVim plugin fixed this issue already.

Comment: I have this issue still.

Answer (score 2):

You can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>c</kbd> instead of <kbd>ESC</kbd> to switch Vim to normal mode.  Also, as of version 0.33, you can now add new mappings in your ~/.vimrc, so you can for example `inoremap jk <ESC>` `inoremap kj <ESC>` and then use the <kbd>j</kbd><kbd>k</kbd> chord to exit insert mode.